# POST request works with Postman but not with axios.post()

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

I created a Note app in `React-JS` and a `REST-api` using node and I am running both the front-end and the server concurrently .
This is my REST-Api (I am using mongoDB to store the data)

```
app.post('/api/post',(req,res)=>{
let title = req.body.title
let content = req.body.content
console.log(title)
console.log(content)
const newNote = new Note ({
        title: title,
        content: content
    })
newNote.save()})
```

This is my axios.post in my App.jsx file

```
function addItem(item){
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/post",{
  title:item.title,
  content:item.content
})
.then(res =>{
  console.log(res)
})
.catch(error=>{
  console.log(error)
})}
```

The POST request works perfectly via Postman and my data gets stored. However for the axios.post function it does send a post request back to my api, but when I `console.log(title)` and `console.log(content)` the console returns undefined and an empty object gets sent back to my Note collection in my mongoDB database.I have tried finding the problem online but have not been able to find the solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my entire express rest API code

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true})) //this line is to parse any information from forms
app.use(cors())
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
const PORT = 4000

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/keeperDB');
}

const notesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {title:String,
    content:String}
)
const Note = mongoose.model("Note",notesSchema)

app.get("/api", function(req, res){
  Note.find(function(err,results){
    if (err){
      console.log(err)
    }else{
        res.json(results)   
    }
  })
});
app.post('/api/post',(req,res)=>{

    let title = req.body.title
    let content = req.body.content
    console.log(title)
    console.log(content)
    const newNote = new Note ({
            title: title,
            content: content
        })
    newNote.save()
})


app.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

`

Comment: did your browser console have any errors?

Comment: my browser console did not have any outputs at all @AselaPriyadarshana

Comment: please add your express rest API code which includes express middleware

Comment: hi, I have added my express file @AselaPriyadarshana

Comment: Try to add app.use(express.json()) after app.use(cors()) codeline

Comment: You're most welcome, So what's the missing part of your code?

Comment: @AselaPriyadarshana hi I have added app.use(express.json()) and it worked, thanks so much.

Comment: yes, That's why I inform your earlier, anyway happy to help you and I added this solution as an answer to your question then It will help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `app.use(express.json())` middleware to you're code otherwise express server can't extract JSON data from request

Answer (score 0):

It seems Your request object is not a `JSON` object and you need to use `app.use(express.json())`.